# PowerBuilder to other running server connection

Tags: web-services, sybase, powerbuilder

please help...
I want to use the web services of an application server(java application server) Which is running on the localhost:9000 on my system  in my powerbuilder 8  application.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What kind of web service? SOAP?

Answer (score 0):

Are you saying you want to use your local workstation (localhost) as the production backend server for your application?  That's definitely NOT a good idea.